# javascript drag and drop, addeventlister. - totally lost

Tags: javascript, mobile, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener

Hey I don't like asking such open questions but, I'm quite lost with this one. I'm trying to figure out how to do drag and drop specifically for touch devices. All the online tutorials I've seen for drag and drop have some weird if(IE) statements that make it hard to read and then they don't even work on touch devices. It's driving me crazy because this is so easy to do in actionScript and I'm still learning JS.

Much to my dismay I couldn't even get addEventListener to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag and Drop test</title>
<style type="text/css">

#box{
top:200px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
position:relative;
}

#box2{
top:200px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
position:relative;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">something something something</div>

<div id="box2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function doSomething() {
  myImage.style.width = '200px';
}

var myImage = document.getElementById('box');

myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I actually pulled this code for addEventListener from the answer of another question but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm running safari if that is important. Thanks

Comment: To ease the pain of writing cross-browser DOM code, I strongly suggest you have a look at some Javascript frameworks, like Jquery or Dojo.

Comment: I just wanted to learn it in Javascript first so I could understand it not just use it. Does that make sense? Also, I'm not interested in providing cross-browser support for this particular project.

Comment: Of course. It just happens to be that manipulating the DOM, styling things and handling events is the most frustrating part.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use a JavaScript framework.  The complexity of DD in a desktop web app is hard enough, let alone on a mobile device.  Take a look at [YUI3's Drag and Drop](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/dd/).  It has some kind of mobile support:

> Native gesture support was added to DD in 3.2.0. This support is
>   transparent and the implementor should not have to do anything to use
>   this functionality. When dd is used, loader will check the device to
>   see if it contains support for Gesture Events, if the device supports
>   these events the dd-gestures module will automatically be loaded as
>   well as it's dependencies. At this point, DD will operate as usual but
>   it will utilize the native gesture events instead of mouse based
>   events.